# how to use mkpasswd to generate a password in shadow file in ubuntu 10 lucid

Tags: administration

Today I upgrade my server to ubuntu 10 lucid, The first thing that occur to me is the new encrypted method, it's the default line

```
root:$6$ih6NzSZL$NuK0cjnATfIS3ets.MWM3iN3/U.sPh..USCbZ/kyOATm0hpiuZkbWhgaenNKIf23d9HTE/fKnLo0PDV1UCefu0:15333:0:99999:7:::
```

since it starts with $6$, I figured out it's sha-512 method, so I tried to use mkpasswd tool

mkpasswd -m sha-512 123456

so I add a new line to the shadow file

```
yozloy:$6$4KhKoABHknIc$KY3DBvrkLPSXBnS/NZjdxrdw2EY02fDQcclf8/B3P7ymSeCBsKWyRC.zgRcklTWwmNLplWLgcAKenFzrvq6ub0:15318:0:9999:7:::
```

but it doesn't work! probably dues to the salt, I don't know what it is, so I didn't specify.

Comment: Why do you not just add the user using `adduser` and set a password using `passwd`?

Comment: @Paul, just want to say what's going under the hound

Answer (score 9):

The salt is in the second field of the password:

```
$id$salt$password
```

So when you create your passwd, pick a salt:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 <password> <salt>
```

Then you'll get a line

```
$6$<salt>$<encrypted password>
```

Then you can add this to your shadow file:

```
yozloy:$6$<salt>$<encrypted password>:...
```

Ie, the salt you specify remains the same in the shadow file as when you type it on the command line

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 12345 -S ih6NzSZL
```

However, be aware that the result might actually be longer the original.

Comment: Is there a quickway to check the password to see if it works?